# How to calculate the total size of certain files only, recursive, in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, diskspace, du

I've got a bunch of files scattered across folders in a layout, e.g.:

```
dir1/somefile.gif
dir1/another.mp4
dir2/video/filename.mp4
dir2/some.file
dir2/blahblah.mp4
```

And I need to find the total disk space used for the MP4 files *only*. This means it's gotta be recursive somehow.

I've looked at `du` and fiddling with piping things to `grep` but can't seem to figure out how to calculate just the MP4 files no matter where they are.

A human readable total disk space output is a must too, preferably in GB, if possible?

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 10):

For individual file size:

```
find . -name "*.mp4" -print0 | du -sh --files0-from=-
```

For total disk space in GB:

```
find . -name "*.mp4" -print0 | du -sb --files0-from=-  | awk '{ total += $1} END { print total/1024/1024/1024 }'
```

Comment: I was also about to suggest the first command. Since you pass `-s` it should already summarize, but hey it lists sizes for each individual file if the `--files0-from` is passed. This looks like a bug, isn't it?

Comment: From man page: `-s, display only a total for each argument`. Here each file passed on standard input is a different argument. `-s` is useful with directories.

Comment: Try to remove the `print0` from find and remove the --files0-from option. Now it will calculate the total while we are still passing multiple file arguments

Comment: It calculates the total of the current directory, completely ignoring `find` output. Not what was asked.

Comment: Damn, you are right.. `du` simply ignores `stdin` per default. Thanks for showing this

Comment: Marco, check by answer

Comment: Note: the `--files0-from` is GNU specific, so for example on OS X or BSD you don't have it...

Comment: `du -ch` prints the grand total in the end of the output

Answer (score 4):

This will sum all mp4 files size in bytes:

```
find ./ -name "*.mp4" -printf "%s\n" | paste -sd+ | bc
```

Answer (score 4):

You can simply do :

```
find -name "*.mp4" -exec du -b {} \; | awk 'BEGIN{total=0}{total=total+$1}END{print total}'
```

The -exec option of find command executes a simple command with {} as the file found by find.
du -b displays the size of the file in bytes.
The awk command initializes a variable at 0 and get the size of each file to display the total at the end of the command.