# how to find largest and smallest .c files in directory

Tags: linux-kernel, navigation, find, du, node.js-fs

I'm trying to find the size of the largest and smallest .c files in the linux kernel fs directory.

Here's what I have:

`find . -type f -name '*.c' | du -ah | sort -nr | head -10`

That just gives me a list of the 10 largest files in the directory, but not the largest .c files. Trying to use -regex '*.c' doesn't work either. Skipping du -ah doesn't list any files. Getting rid of head -10 and just looking at all the names it gives me, it seems like it's only returning directories and files named Kconfig and Makefile, but I thought find -type f was supposed to only give me files.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Try `find . -type f -name '*.c' -printf '%s\t%P\n' | sort -nr | head -n 10`.

Comment: doesn't print anything

Comment: Related and has different solutions, [How to calculate the total size of certain files only, recursive, in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28900112/).

Answer (score 0):

You were quite close, you forgot to use `xargs` before invoking `du`.

```
find . -type f -name '*.c' | xargs du -ah | sort -nr | head -10
```

For the smallest files, remove the reverse argument `-r` for `sort`.

```
find . -type f -name '*.c' | xargs du -ah | sort -n | head -10
```

[`xargs`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html):

> build and execute command lines from standard input